# Increase Pod disk size

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a k8s deployment that requires large ssd local storage for high performance file read/write. All nodes attached to the cluster have large ssd volumes (350GB). This is the

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations: {}
  labels:
    name: main
  name: main
  namespace: fileaccessor
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 30
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: main
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations: {}
      labels:
        name: main
    spec:
      containers:
        - args: []
          command:
            - /app/fileaccessor
          env: []
          image: ----:fileaccessor
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: main
          ports: []
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "2"
          stdin: false
          tty: false
          volumeMounts: []
      imagePullSecrets: []
      initContainers: []
      serviceAccountName: fileaccessor
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes: []
```

After the pod start, I log in and inspect the disk. It only has 20GB of disk size.

```
bash-5.0# df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                  20.0G     17.7G      2.3G  88% /
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    15.5G         0     15.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1           20.0G     17.7G      2.3G  88% /dev/termination-log
/dev/nvme0n1p1           20.0G     17.7G      2.3G  88% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/nvme0n1p1           20.0G     17.7G      2.3G  88% /etc/hostname
/dev/nvme0n1p1           20.0G     17.7G      2.3G  88% /etc/hosts
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    15.5G     12.0K     15.5G   0% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs                    15.5G      4.0K     15.5G   0% /run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount
tmpfs                    15.5G         0     15.5G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/kcore
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/keys
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/latency_stats
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/timer_list
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/sched_debug
tmpfs                    15.5G         0     15.5G   0% /sys/firmware
```

I did some search on Internet but I didn't find any method to increase the pod disk size without specifying a volume. Do I have to specify a local volume in order to get a bigger size?
Also for deployment, is it possible to use a volume mount? It seems most of the examples are for Pod.

Comment: ssh to the node and show me the output of `df -ha`

Answer (score 0):

Am I understand right that you using Amazon EKS?
In my case, default disk size was 80G by default, and to increase it I set *volumeSize* to cluster.yaml:

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig

metadata:
  name: @CLUSTER_NAME@
  region: eu-west-1
  version: "1.21"

nodeGroups:
  - name: @CLUSTER_NAME@-nodegroup
    instanceType: r5.24xlarge
    minSize: 1
    desiredCapacity: 1
    maxSize: 30
    volumeSize: 1024
...
```

To ensure your node storage size, run

```
kubectl describe node <node>
```

and find "ephemeral-storage" in output